# Trying to access another closure's property from a Gradle test task

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, gradle

First, my real goal is to inform my functional tests on which port Gradle will start my development server (with [this plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin), if you're interested). The simplest way to do that seems to be setting a system property. So here's what I'm trying to do:

```
appengine {
  httpPort = 8081
  ...
}

test {
  systemProperty "httpPort", appengine.httpPort
}
```

I'm still pretty new to Gradle and probably just don't know my Groovy scoping rules well enough, but it should be possible to do something like this, right? I've seen using a "global `def`" to do this sort of thing, but it seems like there's a more elegant solution for this particular case.

Comment: Yes, this should be fine. What's the real question?

Comment: It's encouraged to access task or extension properties to retrieve its value. As a side note: In this specific case the plugin already defines a `SourceSet` for functional tests. You should put your source into the configured source directory of this `SourceSet` and use the task `appengineFunctionalTest` instead of using the standard unit test source directory.

Comment: Huh, so my example usage should be correct? It was giving me errors that within the `test` closure it didn't know how to interpret `appengine`. Maybe I had a typo earlier; I'll give it another try. And yes, I'm using the `functionalTest` directory as well as the `appengineFunctionalTest` task. Thanks both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, here's the trick: I wanted to pass the system property to my functional tests in particular. For some reason I though a `test` closure was the right place for that and that the `appengineFunctionalTest` task would inherit from that, but that's not the case. Once I changed my `test` closure to `appengineFunctionalTest` specifically, Gradle was able to connect the dots. I'm still a little mystified by the scoping rules here, but I'm sure I'll learn. :)

```
appengine {
  httpPort = 8081
  ...
}

appengineFunctionalTest {
  systemProperty "httpPort", httpPort
}
```

So unfortunately, it looks like this Q&A is now specifically about the App Engine Gradle plugin referenced in the question. Thanks to the commenters who helped!